# How to get perl/dbmopen

Tags: perl, ubuntu-11.04

I want to install latex2html and it complains that it can't find `dbmopen`:

```
$ ./configure 
loading cache ./config.cache
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking whether #! works in shell scripts... yes
launching proprietary configuration...

config.pl, Release 2006-1 (Revision )
Accompanies LaTeX2HTML, (C) 1999 GNU Public License.

checking for old config file (cfgcache.pm)... not found (ok)
checking for platform... linux (assuming unix)
checking for /usr/bin/perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking perl version... 5.010001
checking if perl supports some dbm... no
Error: Perl reported DBM error: dbmopen failed
LaTeX2HTML needs some DBM.
```

I am on ubuntu 11.4 and have no clue where to get `dbmopen` (or what this really is). What should I do to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is odd, `dbmopen` is core function in Perl 5.  Try running this on the commandline:

```
perl -le 'dbmopen my %h, "/tmp/foo", 0600 or die $!; $h{foo} = 5; print $h{foo}'
```

If that prints `5` to the screen then you have `dbmopen` and it works (which I fully expect to be the case).  I don't know what `latex2html` is doing in its configure script, but if the code above works, it must be something wrong.  It might be a permission error, `dbmopen` creates a file, so you may want to check where that file is being created and if you have permission to create a file there.

Comment: It prints `5`. I'll investigate further. Its already good to that the problem is not in a missing dbmopen function. Thanks!